# Swift Stripe Saving Card Integration

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails

I have recently developed an iOS application using swift that does the basic Stripe functionality as mentioned in the Stripe example. However, my app requires saving card details with payment being made at certain times in the system. I am aware that a customer object needs to be created, store the id and then charge in reference to this id. My issue is when using the server side code provided by Stripe I am unable to create a customer or charge. If anyone has any suggestions that would be most appreciated!

Comment: this question is too generic.. you need to think about it more and edit your question

Comment: The error code is 503 which means there is no customer object created because at the time of creation a payment token is not available

Answer (score 0):

I have also had this issue when I first started to use Stripe.

The first thing I did was to review the standard Stripe integration guide to make sure all the dependencies were added to the pod file, that they were installed,  and that I had deployed to a backend in my case Heroku and then added the backend base url in the CheckoutViewController.

I also checked to make sure that my  ViewControllers had the proper target membership selected.

I also made sure the app delegate had the Stripe publishable key added in the func didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

Once I did all that I was able to  process a purchase from my app on my device and see  a new customer, a new credit card, and a new charge in my Stripe Dashboard.

EVENT

cus_C4jHIFBjr12qoy was charged $1.99
Customer cus_C4jHIFBjr12qoy added a new MasterCard ending in 4444
cus_C4jHIFBjr12qoy's details were updated
cus_C4jHIFBjr12qoy is a new customer

I am also able to add additional credit cards during a session, but I still have not figured out how to retrieve an existing client id from the backend or stripe so I can retrieve stored credit cards so the user does not have to reenter the credit card information every time they use the app.

A good resource to check out is : http://webchat.freenode.net to see what other developers are doing to integrate Stripe into their apps.

Here is a link to a YouTube Video on Stripe which you may find useful:
Part 1 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NdszUvzroxQ&t=233s 
there is also a Part 2 which actually shows how to create charges and configure the backend. Hope this helps.